# File System in User Space (FUSE)

Tags: c, linux, filesystems, fuse

I am trying to implement a file system using fuse. What are the functions of fuse_operations that need to be implemented for "read directory" and "read file" operations?

I have tried to implement it by following some tutorial on web but can not fully inderstand it (bbfs file system tutorial https://www.cs.nmsu.edu/~pfeiffer/fuse-tutorial/) and my code is giving segmentation fault?

```
    #define FUSE_USE_VERSION 30
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <ctype.h>
    #include <dirent.h>
    #include <errno.h>
    #include <fcntl.h>
    #include <fuse.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <libgen.h>
    #include <limits.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/xattr.h>

    struct uafs_state {
         char *rootdir;
    };

    #define UAFS_DATA ((struct uafs_state *) fuse_get_context()->private_data)

    static void uafs_fullpath(char fpath[PATH_MAX], const char *path)
    {
        strcpy(fpath, UAFS_DATA->rootdir);
        strncat(fpath, path, PATH_MAX);
    }

    int error_check(int retstat)
    {
        if (retstat < 0) {
            retstat = -errno;
        }

        return retstat;
    }

    int uafs_getattr(const char *path, struct stat *buf)
    {
        printf("Reading Attributes.........\n");
        int retstat;
        char fpath[PATH_MAX];

        uafs_fullpath(fpath, path);
        retstat = error_check(lstat(fpath, buf));

        return retstat;
    }

    int uafs_readdir(const char *path, void *buf, fuse_fill_dir_t       filler, off_t offset, struct fuse_file_info *fi)
    {
        printf("Reading Directory.....\n");
        int retstat = 0;
        DIR *dp;
        struct dirent *de;
        dp = (DIR *) (uintptr_t) fi->fh;
        de = readdir(dp);
        if (de == 0) {
            retstat = -errno;
            return retstat;
        }

        do {
            if (filler(buf, de->d_name, NULL, 0) != 0) {
                return -ENOMEM;
            }
        } while ((de == readdir(dp)) != NULL);

        return retstat;
    }

    int uafs_read(const char *path, char *buf, size_t size, off_t offset, struct fuse_file_info *fi)
    {
        printf("Reading file.....\n");
        int retstat = 0;
        retstat = pread(fi->fh, buf, size, offset);
        return error_check(retstat);
    }

    struct fuse_operations uafs_oper = {
        .getattr = uafs_getattr,
        .readdir = uafs_readdir,    
        .read = uafs_read,
    };

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        int fuse_stat;
        struct uafs_state *uafs_data;

        if ((getuid() == 0) || (geteuid() == 0)) {
            printf("Error\n");
            return 1;
        } 

        if ((argc < 3) || (argv[argc-2][0] == '-') || (argv[argc-1][0] == '-')) {
            abort();
        }
        uafs_data = malloc(sizeof(struct uafs_state));
        if (uafs_data == NULL) {
            abort();
        }

        uafs_data->rootdir = realpath(argv[argc-2], NULL);
        argv[argc-2] = argv[argc-1];
        argv[argc-1] = NULL;

        fuse_stat = fuse_main(argc, argv, &uafs_oper, uafs_data);

        return fuse_stat;
     }
```

Comment: Maybe you should provide a link to the tutorial so we can see what you're working with?  The documentation for FUSE should be available on the web, probably close by where you got the source code for FUSE.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler Link for tutorial: https://www.cs.nmsu.edu/~pfeiffer/fuse-tutorial/

Comment: Please edit that information into the question.